# What is the relationship between time complexity and the number of steps in an algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity

**For large values of n, an algorithm that takes 20000n^2 steps has better time complexity (takes less time) than one that takes 0.001n^5 steps**

I believe this statement is true. But, why?

If there are more steps wouldn't that take more time?

Answer (score 0):

[Computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms) is considered in the asymptotic sense because the important question is usually of scaling. Even with your clear case, the `^5` algorithm begins to take longer around 275 items - which isn't very many. See this figure from [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.001n%5E5%2C+20000n%5E2):

[image: intersection of given complexities]

Quoting from the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms) linked above:

> Usually asymptotic estimates are used because different implementations of the same algorithm may differ in efficiency. However the efficiencies of any two "reasonable" implementations of a given algorithm are related by a constant multiplicative factor called a hidden constant.

All that said, if you have two comparable algorithms and the one with less complexity has a significant constant coefficient and you're only going to process 10 items, then it very well may be a good idea to choose the less efficient one. Some common libraries even switch algorithms depending upon the size of the data being processed; this is called [a hybrid algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_algorithm) and Python's `sorted` implementation, [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) uses it to switch between insertion sort and merge sort.

Comment: Huh... I just realized I was looking at it the wrong way the whole time. Thank you very much. So, to be clear.                                                                                                                                                                    - One algorithm might be faster than algorithm 2 in one case and slower in another, depending on the size of the input.                                                                                   - Depending on the problem or situation, different complexities and efficiencies are suitable.

Comment: Yes, though in terms of textbook computational complexity, the coefficient is ignored. If my answer helped you, consider accepting it!